# How to darken the rest of the webpage when hovering over a link in the navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On amazon.com when you hover on a link in the navbar that has a dropdown the rest of the page below the navbar darkens or becomes less bright.
I tried googling and trying to find the answer in the homepage's code but its too completed and didn't work and I didn't find anything useful on google either. If anyone can figure it out please share a jsfiddle

Comment: make a dark background and opacity:0.5 on the main page

Comment: I tried linking the links and the rest of page with css classes but if it can be done that way I couldn't figure it out

Comment: js was invented for that. why not use it?

Comment: not very good at js

Answer (score 2):

Example html:

```
 <div id="nav"> some links </div>
 <div id="main"> main content</div>
```

the js:

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
    nav=document.getElementById("nav");
    main=document.getElementById("main");
    links= nav.document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(key=0; key<links.length;key++){
       link=links[key];
       link.onmouseover=function(){
          main.style.opacity=0.5;
       };
       link.onmouseout=function(){
         main.style.opacity=1;
       };
   }
 };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have options for this. They did this with `javascript`, on  `mouseover` event. When the mouse is over that specific link, it adds style to that overlay div.

Here is a snippet:

```js
$("li a").on("mouseover", function(){
  $("#nav-cover").addClass("on");
}).on("mouseleave", function(){
  $("#nav-cover").removeClass("on");
})
```

```css
#nav-cover.on {
    z-index: 1;
    height: 1899px;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.links {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 6;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
.links a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#nav-cover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    background-color: #000;
    -ms-filter: opacity(.6);
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    -webkit-opacity: .6;
    -moz-opacity: .6;
    -o-opacity: .6;
    opacity: .6;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="links">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Hover Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="nav-cover"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Z-index your navbar 10 for example. Then at Z-index of 9 create a div called overlay. Style the overlay so that it has an rgba of (0,0,0, 0.7) or so. Then on hover just toggle the visibility or display of it. Here is an example:

Heres the code:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="navbar"></div>
<div id="overlay"></div>

<style>
#content {
 width: 600px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: green;
 float: left;
}

#navbar {
 width: 600px;
 height: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 9;
 background-color: blue;
}

#overlay {
 width: 600px;
 height: 300px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 9;
 visibility: hidden;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}   

#navbar:hover + #overlay {
 visibility: visible;
}

</style>
```

Example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/y5gwo230/

Comment: Mine is a pure CSS method that works great, no need for JS or Jquery